# Jquery keyup not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to check available qty with two text box. If entered qty is larger then available qty, then entered qty should be automatically changed to max available qty.

Let say max 5 qty is available and if the user entered 6, I am getting an alert message. But if the user enters 10 then I am not getting alert. I am using following code.

```
<div class="qty-wrapper">
    <label for="qty">Qty</label>
    <input data-productid="100" type="text" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" class="input-text qty hk_qty_text_box" />
    <br><br>
    <label for="qty">Available</label>
    <input readonly style="width: 100px;" type="text" id="avl_qty_100" value="5" class="input-text qty">
</div>


<script>
$('.hk_qty_text_box').on('keyup', function() {

    var productId = $(this).data("productid");
    var avlb_qty = $("#avl_qty_"+productId).val();

    console.log($(this).val() +"===>"+ avlb_qty);

    if($(this).val() > avlb_qty){
        $(this).val(avlb_qty);
        alert("Not enough qty...");
    }
});
</script>
```

Also ID avl_qty_100 value is changing base on selected product using ajax.

Comment: You are comparing strings, use `parseInt()`/`Number()`/`+str` to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let say max 5 qty is available and if user entered 6, i am getting
>   alert message. But if user enter 10 then i am not getting alert.

**You are comparing strings instead of number**. You need to convert `avlb_qty` into a number before comparison

```
var avlb_qty = +$("#avl_qty_"+productId).val(); //using unary + to coerce value to a number

var value = +$(this).val(); //converting $(this).val() to number as well
```

and compare it as

```
if( value > avlb_qty)
{ 
     $(this).val(avlb_qty);
     alert("Not enough qty...");
}
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.hk_qty_text_box').on('keyup', function() {

  var productId = $(this).data("productid");
  var avlb_qty = +$("#avl_qty_" + productId).val();

  console.log($(this).val() + "===>" + avlb_qty);

  var value = +$(this).val();

  if (value > avlb_qty) {
    $(this).val(avlb_qty);
    alert("Not enough qty...");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qty-wrapper">
  <label for="qty">Qty</label>
  <input data-productid="100" type="text" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" class="input-text qty hk_qty_text_box" />
  <br><br>
  <label for="qty">Available</label>
  <input readonly style="width: 100px;" type="text" id="avl_qty_100" value="5" class="input-text qty">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gurvinder for quick reply. I used parseInt before but for somehow it was not working. Your solution is working perfectly.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the string to an integer using `parseInt`.

JS

```
$('.hk_qty_text_box').on('keyup', function() {

        var productId = $(this).data("productid");
        var avlb_qty = parseInt($("#avl_qty_"+productId).val());


        if(parseInt($(this).val()) > avlb_qty){
            $(this).val(avlb_qty);
            alert("Not enough qty...");
        }
    });
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/xpvt214o/60932/)